# Highcharts: Removing the legend Symbol that comes with marker

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart with **marker enabled**. I also have my own custom legend Formatter

```
legend: {
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: true,
        labelFormatter: function() {
            let symbol = '<span style="color:' + this.color + ';font-size:12px;">&#9644;</span>';
            return '<span style="font-size: 12px;">' + symbol +  ' ' + this.name  +  '</span>';
        }
    }
```

Because of my marker, I get an additional line next to my custom legend symbol. I tried destroying my marker symbols using this solution
LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/Tr7nk/2621/
But , I am getting errors when toggling the legends

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSVG' of undefined
    at E.destroy (highcharts.src.js:4424)
    at t.<anonymous> (chart.component.ts:271)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of destroying the legend symbol, you can set `symbolWidth` to 0, to make it invisible.

```
    legend: {
        ...,
        symbolWidth: 0
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mwpu26sj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.symbolWidth

Comment: another method that worked for me was, instead of destroying the legend symbol, we can hide them
`if (serie.legendSymbol )
            serie.legendSymbol.hide()`